# OpenERP IE Visibility Problem

Tags: internet-explorer, odoo

i have buttons in openerp which are dynamically visible on certain conditions in my module when i run this n IE8 all the buttons are visible and fields which are set to be dyamic visible..But when i run my module in compatibiity mode. it all works..I want to know why it fails in IE8 w/o compatibility mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks i got the solution. actually in form.js where it hides the field in that parent is getting null in case of IE. now solved. Thanks